# In Zend Framework 2, what are the different routing types and how is each one used?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework2

I have defined a module in ZendFramework 2 and I am going through the [standard ZF2 tutorial on their website](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/genindex.html).

In the example given the type is defined like so: `'type' => 'segment'`. What are the other types of routes and what are some typical use cases for each one?

Answer (score 1):

All possible route types are :

```
'hostname', 'literal', 'part', 'regex', 'scheme', 'segment', 'query', 'method'
```

The usage of those is described in the [official documentation here](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.mvc.routing.html).

Although, there is one extra type called 'wildcard' which is possible according to the source, but it is not described in documentation.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what Jevgeni just posted, you may also be interested in [DASPRiDs Router Presentation from ZendCon 2012](http://www.dasprids.de/blog/2012/10/23/slides-for-my-zf2-router-presentation)